# get first word of an ACF field

Tags: php, string, wordpress, html, custom-fields

I'm using ACF on my wordpress website, and to create a div id I would like to get the first word from a AC Field.
For example, I have a field called "Titre", and the text inside is for example Made Under Authority.
I need to create a  like this :

```
<div id="<?php the_sub_field('titre'); ?">
```

I'm using Anchors on my website that's why I need to do this.
It works fine, with one word fields, but in this case my div will be

```
<div id="Made Under Authority">
```

so it won't works with the blank spaces...

what I need is to only get the first word from my text field to generate my div name, and in lowercase.
I know how do it with a normal text, but not with ACF... Anybody can help me ?

here is my PHP code

```
<?php if(get_field('album')): ?>
<?php while(has_sub_field('album')): ?>
<div id="<?php the_sub_field('titre'); ?>">
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>  
<?php endif; ?>
```

thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all use `get_sub_field` instead of `the_sub_field`. "the" will echo string automatically, "get" will return it.

So your code could look like this:

`<div id="<?php echo strtolower(explode(' ', get_sub_field('titre'), 2)[0]) ?>">`

But as far as I remember this will for PHP 5.4 (because `explode(...)[0]`) thing.

**EDIT**

Without `explode` but with `strtok`:

`<div id="<?php echo strtolower(strtok(get_sub_field('titre'), ' ')) ?>">`